# The extension package size exceeds the maximum package size limit

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, marketplace

I made a **custom extension** task in ***VS Code***. And, I'm facing a problem while uploading the extension package to **Marketplace**. It's showing an error: "*The extension package size '32440237 bytes' exceeds the maximum package size '26214400 bytes*" as my extension size is ~32MB.

When I looked deep, then I got like `node_modules` folder (where all packages are present) size is increasing if I install some external packages like:

- `azure-pipelines-task-lib`
- `azure-pipelines-tasks-azure-arm-rest-v2`
- `@pulumi/azure`

I also tried the solution which was given in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks/issues/165). But, no luck.

I'm worried, is there any way to decrease or compress the size of `node_modules` or `extension-package`.

or,

How the size is increasing for the `node_modules` folder?

if anyone has knowledge on this, please let me know.

*Thanks in Advance!!*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer to this.

First thing, in VS Marketplace, the default size of uploading the extension package is 25MB.

So, if your extension package exceeds the max size limit, then don't worry, just do one thing:

- Mail your issue to this mail id: ***vsmarketplace@microsoft.com***. Then, one of from support team will contact you within 24hrs-48hrs.

Lastly, they will ask you the reason for extending the size limit, then you have to give the proper reason. Then, bingo!!

Your issue will resolve within 2-3 days max.